# How to extract detected object using object's bounding box and display it in sub image?

Tags: matlab

I have detected an object and then draw its bounding box using `regionprops`. I have tried but I am unable to crop the bounding box and display it in another sub image.

```
S = regionprops(BWfinal, 'Area','Eccentricity','Centroid','BoundingBox');

All_areas = vertcat(S.Area);

[MaxArea, MaxAreaIdx] = (max(All_areas(:)));

All_BB = vertcat(S.BoundingBox);

PotA = find(All_areas==MaxArea);

imshow(g)
hold on

for k = 1:numel(PotA)
    rectangle('Position',All_BB(PotA(k),:),'EdgeColor','y','LineWidth',2)
end
```

kindly if anyone can help?